# Loop through all the records of datablock in Oracle forms

Tags: forms, oracle

I am trying to learn Oracle forms (v6.0). In a when-button-pressed trigger I am trying to loop through all of the records from a datablock. So far I have following code:

```
BEGIN
    GO_BLOCK('MY_BLOCK');
    FIRST_RECORD;
    LOOP
    MESSAGE(:MY_BLOCK.DSP_NAME);
    EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'TRUE';
    NEXT_RECORD;            
    END LOOP;   
END;
```

When I run the code all the DSP_NAME values are displayed except the last one. If I add :

```
MESSAGE(:MY_BLOCK.DSP_NAME);
```

after the loop, then the DSP_NAME value of the last record is displayed. Why it is like that - the message is displayed before the last record check? and what would be the right way to loop through the records?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your loop is correct. I suspect the last message is showing up in the status bar at the bottom of the form instead of as a popup window.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I thought an message box will show up on every iteration and got confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get a pop up window use the same line twice :

```
MESSAGE(:MY_BLOCK.DSP_NAME);

MESSAGE(:MY_BLOCK.DSP_NAME);
```

You'll get it this way.